# How to find physical and logical core number in a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, hyperthreading

Are there kernel functions in Linux that would return the number of the physical core and
logical core (in case of Hyperthreading) on which a kernel module is running ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at the end of `include/linux/smp.h`: `smp_processor_id()`
gives you the number of the current executing CPU. `get_cpu()` will do
the same and will also disable preemption so that you will stay on
that CPU until `put_cpu()` is called.

From user-space, you can use `sched_getcpu()` or `getcpu()` to obtain the same information.