# Find number of CPUs in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want detect number of CPUs in linux kernel and write a sys_call that find it.

[cpuinfo_x86](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.12#L83) gives features of one CPU and cpu_detect fills it but how to find number of CPUs to detect?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: How come this is not a programming question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the MACRO `NR_CPUS` we can find the number of CPU. 
This Macro should not be used in early_init sequence Since mostly NR_CPUS will not be initialized as it is run time macro.

or you can use `num_online_cpus()` function to get the number of cpus online.

you can find more options in `include/linux/cpumask.h` header to find availability of CPUS in various kinds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nr_cpu_ids](https://web.archive.org/web/20170120175423/http://lxr.free-electrons.com:80/source/include/linux/cpumask.h?#L37) variable which is set by all architectures during kernel boot up and initialization.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$lscpu
```

This gives me information about CPUs, as well as architecture,  etc...

Comment: The question is about finding information from **the kernel**, not from the *user space*.

Comment: In that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315907/how-to-find-physical-and-logical-core-number-in-a-kernel-module

Comment: The referenced question is about a number of *current CPU*, not about of **total CPU** number.

Comment: in kernel mode not in user space

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I cat /proc/cpuinfo to learn about the CPUs on a machine.

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo  |grep processor |wc -l

Comment: yeah, i indeed missed the mark on this answer completely.