# kernel API to return now running cpu number

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, cpu

I am looking for a Linux kernel API that returns the core number currently executing the task. So I want to know in my code on which particular core is being executed.

Comment: I found answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315907/how-to-find-physical-and-logical-core-number-in-a-kernel-module/7316216

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find physical and logical core number in a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315907/how-to-find-physical-and-logical-core-number-in-a-kernel-module)

Comment: judging by the answers, it seems unclear you are talking about user context or kernel context.

Answer (score 3):

typically when you are locking a process to a core you use `get_cpu` this is to prevent preemption so that your process doesn't suddenly move to another CPU.  If you *know* that you're not going to be preempted you can use `smp_processor_id` to get the CPU id.

```
  #include/asm/smp.h
  
  static int my_cpu() {
       return smp_processor_id();
  }
```

### NOTES

CPU ids are between 0 and NR_CPUS and they are *not necessarily continuous*

Answer (score 0):

Already answered:

[how can I get the processor ID of the current process in C in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358681/how-can-i-get-the-processor-id-of-the-current-process-in-c-in-linux)

See man page:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html

tldr:

```
#include <linux/getcpu.h>

int getcpu(unsigned *cpu, unsigned *node, struct getcpu_cache *tcache);
```